Slow upload speed in KVM
I have an infrastructure with a bare metal server with Fedora 40. On this server I am running several virtual machines with libvirt (eg: Fedora, AlmaLinux, Debian). I can access this VMs via WireGuard VPN from my home Windows PC, where the VPN gateway is the (bare metal) host server. Or I can forward a port directly to one of the VMs (eg: port 54321 on host to port 22 on vm).
I have an issue regarding with the upload speed of virtual machines, regardless of the access method. When I am testing the network speed with iperf3 between a vm and another physical server (not in the same server room even) everything is fine.
On the other hand, when I want to download files to my home Windows PC from a vm, the network speed is poor (about 70-80 kb/s, but the upload from Windows to vm is perfect). If I run a test Linux machine in my PC in VMware Player, the speed is perfect between the kvm Linux on the bare metal server and the test Linux machine in VMware on Windows. But the speed between the kvm and my Windows PC is still bad.
There is a workaround I found, disable tx-tcp-segmentation with this command on the kvm machines:
ethtool -K enp1s0 tx-tcp-segmentation off

If I issue this command, the upload speed of the kvm machine to the Windows PC will be fine.
There is a same infrastructure (let's say a backup) where everything matches except the host OS (not Fedora 40, but Debian 12). The problem does not exist on this system (i.e. tx-tcp-segmentation is on in every kvm Linux machine.)
The question is what is the difference and why do I need to turn off tx-tcp-segmentation to resolve this issue. What is this problem at all?

Do both hosts provide the same virtual Ethernet device type to the VMs? Do they run different QEMU versions?

Interface parameters are the same.
driver: tun
version: 1.6
firmware-version:
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: tap
supports-statistics: no
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
Qemu:
Debian:
$ qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 7.2.11 (Debian 1:7.2+dfsg-7+deb12u6)
Copyright (c) 2003-2022 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
Fedora:
$ qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 8.2.2 (qemu-8.2.2-1.fc40)
Copyright (c) 2003-2023 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

tap is the host-side interface, it doesn't really matter much – are the guest side interface drivers the same? i.e. virtio vs e1000e vs...? It could be just the difference in qemu versions alone (as all those NICs are emulated by qemu, so of course there are likely to be changes from 7.2 to 8.2), but I was guessing that the two VMs might be using different ones.

All guest side interface are the same
$ sudo ethtool -i enp1s0
driver: virtio_net
version: 1.0.0
firmware-version:
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
Yeah, it could be the qemu version difference, but it's strange that it's fine from Linux but doesn't from Windows.
